# Retrofit ListView

Tags: android, mysql, retrofit

I am pretty new to android..

I am trying to retrieve data from MySQL using Retrofit..

I found nothing error in my Code but when I run the application from device it stucks on Progress Dialog Fetching Data...

Below are my codes for fetching the data

```
private void getBooks(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Mengambil Data..","Silahkan Tunggu...",false,false);
    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(ROOT_URL)
            .build();

    BookAPI api = adapter.create(BookAPI.class);
    api.getBooks(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void success(List<Book> list, Response response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            books = list;
            showList();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
}

private void showList(){
    String[] items = new String[books.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i<books.size();i++){
        items[i] = books.get(i).getName();
    }

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list,items);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and also below the Interface I have

```
public interface BookAPI {
@GET("/retrofit/listdata.php")
public void getBooks(Callback<List<Book>> response);
}
```

and finally my php file for listing data named listdata.php

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or die('Cannot connect to   the DB');
mysqli_select_db($link, 'retrofit') or die('Cannot select the DB');
$query = "SELECT * from tbl_book";
$rs= mysqli_query($link,$query) or die('Errorquery:  '.$query);
$countrow=  mysqli_affected_rows($link);
$items = array();  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($rs)){  

array_push($items, $row);  

}  
if($countrow >0){
//$result["errorcode"] = "1";  
$result = $items;  
}else{
 $result["errormsg"] = "Tidak ada data";  
}  

echo json_encode($result);  
?>
```

Please help me.. I am stuck on this situation.. Is it because I use the php file instead of json file on my Interface?

Would be very appreciated for any response and help..

Comment: check with your `failure()`, you might be getting some error

Comment: put `loading.dismiss();` in side your `failure()` method ........... OR use this link it help you https://github.com/sushildlh/AllProjetcs/wiki/Retrofit---Firebase..............

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a RecyclerView and Retrofit in a demo poject,it has the SwipeView layout (Pull to Refresh).Kindly check the repository below. 
https://github.com/frankodoom/Retrofit-RecyclerVew